# Get all checked boxes from datatable that are in different pages

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am using datatable plug-in to use pagination for my table. The first column of my table has checkboxes with value = some uniqueID.

I cannot seem to get all checkbox values including the ones that are already checked.

When I click on the "get checked records", it should only display the unique checkbox values.
Any suggestions?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css">    
  </head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th><input type="checkbox" name='all' id="checkAll"> All</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="1"></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="2"></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="3" checked></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009-01-12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="4"></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012-03-29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="5"></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008-11-28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="6"></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012-12-02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="7"></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012-08-06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="8"></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010-10-14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="9"></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009-09-15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="10"></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="11"></td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008-12-19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="12"></td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013-03-03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="13"></td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008-10-16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="14"></td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012-12-18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="15"></td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010-03-17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="16"></td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012-11-27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="17"></td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010-06-09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="18"></td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009-04-10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="19"></td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012-10-13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="20"></td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012-09-26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="21"></td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011-09-03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="22"></td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009-06-25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="23"></td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011-12-12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="24" checked></td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010-09-20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="25"></td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009-10-09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="26"></td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010-12-22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="27"></td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010-11-14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <button id="get-values">get checked records</button>
    <br/>
    <div id="selected">
    </div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            var table = new DataTable('#example', {
                responsive: true,
                "lengthMenu": [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
                "pageLength": 10
            }); 

                             
            $('#example').on( 'click', '.select-employee', function () {
                var checked = $(this).prop('checked');  // Get checkbox state
                
                // Get row data
                var row = $( this ).closest( 'tr' );
                var data = table.row ( row ).data();
                
                //update the cell data with the checkbox state
                if ( checked ) {
                    data.check = 1;
                } else {
                    data.check = 0;
                }
            });  

            $('#get-values').on('click', function () {
                var checkedRows = [];
                table.rows().every( function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
                    var data = this.data();
                
                    if (data.check === 1) {
                        checkedRows.push(data);
                    }
                });
                console.log('Checked rows via API');
                console.log(checkedRows);
                $('#selected').html(checkedRows);
            });     
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's not displayed on the screen, you can retrieve them; but what's causing them to be checked? Perhaps you can store the checked values in a variables that persists between pages, such as localStorage.

Comment: My example above is displaying the whole row even though it is not the current page displayed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to find the correct datatables resource on jsFiddle to make this work. Do you mean each `checkedRows` item contains the entire row of data rather than just 0 or 1?

Comment: you mean you only want to "get checked records" for current displayed page only?

Comment: @ChrisG but then OP commented: "My example above is displaying the whole row even though it is not the current page displayed." I'm not entirely sure what that means, but it seems they don't want rows in "not the current page displayed"

Comment: @KFNinja could you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: I think his problem is that he wants to display every selected user value (not the whole row). Which is not happening. When you load his code you will notice that `Ashton Cox` is already checked but when you press the button nothing happens. It will print an empty array

Comment: This question is using the tag `datatable` but it should be using the tag `datatables`. Hover your mouse over any tag to read a summary.

Comment: Variations of this question have been [asked many times](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+datatables+access+checkboxes) on Stack Overflow. You can see if any of those questions contain any helpful guidance, and show us what you found. The solution often comes down to needing to use the DataTables API to access those records which exist in your DataTable but which are not currently rendered (not shown in the current page of the table). Your code seems to be doing that already, but it's worth a look at other answers for guidance.

Comment: it makes sense that the already checked user is not printing becuz you only add `data.check = 1` on click. Is not going to affect data already checked on page load

Comment: Also take a look at [`node()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().node()) - for cells, rows, and columns. You probably need that to ensure you access what has currently been checked by a user.

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into why to create a data.check flag (there may be better or simpler or cleaner ways to achieve the same result)

however, after creating the table the "data.check" flag must be initialized otherwise it will be set correctly only where a click event fire

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            
            var table = new DataTable('#example', {
                responsive: true,
                "lengthMenu": [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
                "pageLength": 10
            }); 
            //since data.check does not exist by default you need to set it  
            //after dataTable initialization
            table.rows().every( function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
                var data = this.data();
                var node =this.node();
                
                if($(data[0]).prop("checked")){
                    data.check = 1;
                } else {
                    data.check = 0;
                }        
            });
                             
            $('#example').on( 'click', '.select-employee', function () {
                var checked = $(this).prop('checked');  // Get checkbox state
                
                // Get row data
                var row = $( this ).closest( 'tr' );
                var data = table.row ( row ).data();
                
                //update the cell data with the checkbox state
                if ( checked ) {
                    data.check = 1;
                } else {
                    data.check = 0;
                }
            });  

            $('#get-values').on('click', function () {
                var checkedRows = [];
                table.rows().every( function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
                    var data = this.data();
                
                    if (data.check === 1) {
                        checkedRows.push(data);
                    }
                });
                console.log('Checked rows via API');
                console.log(checkedRows);
                $('#selected').html(checkedRows);
            });     
        });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css">    
  </head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th><input type="checkbox" name='all' id="checkAll"> All</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="1"></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="2"></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="3" checked></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009-01-12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="4"></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012-03-29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="5"></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008-11-28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="6"></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012-12-02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="7"></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012-08-06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="8"></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010-10-14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="9"></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009-09-15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="10"></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="11"></td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008-12-19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="12"></td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013-03-03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="13"></td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008-10-16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="14"></td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012-12-18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="15"></td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010-03-17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="16"></td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012-11-27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="17"></td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010-06-09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="18"></td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009-04-10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="19"></td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012-10-13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="20"></td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012-09-26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="21"></td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011-09-03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="22"></td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009-06-25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="23"></td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011-12-12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="24" checked></td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010-09-20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="25"></td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009-10-09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="26"></td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010-12-22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="27"></td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010-11-14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <button id="get-values">get checked records</button>
    <br/>
    <div id="selected">
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```